# SharePoint 2010 and "get_groups" method

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hy,

I use the JavaScript API for SharePoint.
I need to know if an user belong to a group.

With SahrePoint 2013, I have succeeded to collect all group of my current user `this.currentUser.get_groups()` but with SharePoint 2010 I have this error on my JS console `The object does not support the property or method "get_groups"`.

Can you help me ?

Samuel_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs since [SP.User.groups property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244862(v=office.15).aspx) was introduced in CSOM API for SharePoint **2013**.

## How to determine if user belongs to a group via JSOM in SharePoint 2010

Example 1

The following example demonstrates how to determine whether current user belongs to the group:

```
function isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupId, OnComplete) {

        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var currentUser = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
        context.load(currentUser);
        var group = context.get_web().get_siteGroups().getById(groupId);
        context.load(group,'Users');
        context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var e = group.get_users().getEnumerator();
            while (e.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = e.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}
```

Usage

```
//Is current user the member of Owners group?
isCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(5, function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
   if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
   {
      console.log('Current user has been granted Full Control permissions (via Owner group)');
   }
});
```

Example 2

```
function isUserMemberOfGroup(userLoginName, groupId, OnComplete) {

        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var user = context.get_web().ensureUser(userLoginName);
        context.load(user);
        var group = context.get_web().get_siteGroups().getById(groupId);
        context.load(group,'Users');
        context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

        function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
            var userInGroup = false;
            var e = group.get_users().getEnumerator();
            while (e.moveNext()) {
                var groupUser = e.get_current();
                if (groupUser.get_id() == user.get_id()) {
                    userInGroup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }  
            OnComplete(userInGroup);
        }

        function OnFailure(sender, args) {
            OnComplete(false);
        }    
}
```

Usage

```
isUserMemberOfGroup('domain\\username', 5, function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
   if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
   {
      console.log('User has been granted Full Control permissions (via Owner group)');
   }
});
```

Comment: This code succeed only if the current user have particularly permissions. My script must succeed for all users.

Comment: It's pretty easy to modify it for a case of specific user, see example 2 in the updated answer.

Comment: Double kudos to you, Vadim.  Not only for provide an example applicable to 2010, but also for showing how to retrieve properly so that the function waits for the response.  THANK YOU